# Average of a Sum in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, subquery

I am having some problems creating a query that gives me the average of a sum. I read a few examples here in stackoverflow and couldn't do it. Can anyone help me to understand how to do this please? This is the data I have:

```
Transaction_x0020_Number  Product_x0020_Code  Sales_x0020_Value  Date        Cashier
000356                    350                 24.99              2010-06-04  131    
000356                    726                 32.99              2010-06-04  131    
000357                    350                 24.99              2010-06-04  131    
000358                    350                 24.99              2010-06-04  131    
000358                    360                 24.99              2010-06-04  131    
000770                    703                 69.99              2010-06-04  130    
000771                    726                 32.99              2010-06-04  130    
000772                    1126                5                  2010-06-04  130    
000773                    482                 32.99              2010-06-04  130    
000774                    600                 32.99              2010-06-04  130    
000775                    350                 24.99              2010-06-04  130
```

Basically I need the average transaction value by cashier. I can't run a basic avg because it will take all rows but each transaction can have multiple rows. At the end I want to have:

```
Cashier| Average|  
131    | 44.31  |(Which comes from the sum divided by 3 transactions not 5 rows)  
130    | 33.15  |  
etc.
```

This is the query I have to SUM the transactions but don't know how or where to include the AVG function.

```
SELECT `products`.`Transaction_x0020_Number`, 
       Sum(`products`.`Sales_x0020_Value`) AS `SUM of Sales_x0020_Value`, 
       `products`.`Cashier`   
  FROM `products`
GROUP BY `products`.`Transaction_x0020_Number`, `products`.`Date`, `products`.`Cashier`
  HAVING (`products`.`Date` ={d'2010-06-04'})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SELECT Cashier,
       Sum(Sales_x0020_Value) / COUNT(DISTINCT Transaction_x0020_Number) AS 'avg'
FROM products 
WHERE Date = {d'2010-06-04'}
GROUP BY Cashier
```

Comment: Ah, 8 seconds earlier, deleted mine (although I don't recall a d{} syntax on MySQL?). no need to know the amount of a transaction if it's going the be averaged indeed.

Comment: On a side note: best solution, but why copying the HAVING clause, instead of just a  WHERE which should be used?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers. This really helps. One last question. What is the difference between Where and Having?

I use a query tool to run my queries and I am in the process of learning.

Thanks again!!

Comment: @chupeman if its interesting for someone: WHERE will leave out not matching rows when reading the rows (or while joining), HAVING is like a postprocessor, lets say you query SELECT * FROM TBL1 HAVING id=1 then ALL Data will be read (even if there is only one id 1 and the tablemay be several Gigabytes of size) AND THEN HAVING will reduce the amount of found rows (mysql MAY optimize this especially query, don't know). But with having you can filter for calculated values in the select-statement that WHERE may can't do (depends on the complexity of the query)